# Arduino: Use Timer in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, timer, arduino, esp8266

I am trying to use a timer to repeatedly change the PWM Output over time to have a smooth transition when the brightness changes. I keep getting this error when trying to compile the code:

> /Users/jt/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SingleColorLight/SingleColorLight.cpp: In constructor 'CSingleColorLight::CSingleColorLight(int)':
>   /Users/jt/Documents/Arduino/libraries/SingleColorLight/SingleColorLight.cpp:13:58: error: cannot convert 'CSingleColorLight::DimmerCallback' from type 'void (CSingleColorLight::)(void*)' to type 'void (*)(void*)'
>          ets_timer_setfn(&Dimmer, this->DimmerCallback, NULL);

Here is my code:

```
class CSingleColorLight {

  private:
    int pin;
    int intensitySetPoint;
    int intensityActual;
    int percentageBuffer;
    ETSTimer Dimmer;
    int dimmerCount;

  public:
    CSingleColorLight(int _pin);
    bool setIntensity(int _intensity);
    int getIntensity(); 
    bool getStatus(void);
    bool setStatus(bool _status); 
    void DimmerCallback(void*);

};
```

and in the cpp file:

```
void CSingleColorLight::DimmerCallback(void*) {
  if(dimmerCount>0){
    dimmerCount--;  
    intensityActual++;
  } else if(dimmerCount<0){
    dimmerCount++;
    intensityActual--;
  } else {
    ets_timer_disarm(&Dimmer);
  } 
  analogWrite(pin, percentageToTime[intensityActual]);
  return;
}
```

It asks for a pointer, right? Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want DimmerCallback to take a void* argument, then you need to name it, like

```
void CSingleColorLight::DimmerCallback(void* x)
```

but you are not using the void* in the code. It looks like you should just get rid of it, so it would be

```
void CSingleColorLight::DimmerCallback()
```

int the cpp and

```
void DimmerCallback();
```

in the header.

A void* argument is a pointer that can point to any data type, it is not the same as void which is just no argument.

Comment: That does worsen it... at least I guess so since the error note is longer:
cannot convert 'CSingleColorLight::DimmerCallback' from type 'void (CSingleColorLight::)()' to type 'void (*)(void*)'
       ets_timer_setfn(&Dimmer, this->DimmerCallback, NULL);